# Canvas element blocking selection

Tags: html, css, paperjs

I am trying to get the selection box below the canvas. I have tried a number of  combinations but have not prevailed. I am using paper.js for the canvas. Also, I know that having the names of colors like I have them is bad but this is a rough prototype site so cut me some slack please. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@simonwep/pickr/dist/themes/classic.min.css" /> <!-- 'classic' theme -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WEBSITE.css">
    <!-- Load the Paper.js library -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/paper/dist/docs/assets/js/paper.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <script src="displayTable.js"></script>
    <canvas id="mycanvas" resize></canvas>

    <label for="backgroundTable">Color for background of table:</label>
    <form action="website.php" method="post">
        <div class="form">
            <select name="userBackgroundSelect" id="userBackgroundSelect">
                <option value="black">Black</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="purple">Purple</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a working code snippet showing what you would like? I guess solving your problem comes to using `z-index` CSS rule and ordering properly your dom, but I can't tell right now.

Comment: hi @arthur.sw . The code is successful when developer tools is open, but otherwise is not. https://imgur.com/a/NMPS81U

Comment: sorry, I can't help without a snippet : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have form below canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198219/how-to-have-form-below-canvas)

Comment: please post a code snippet instead of posting the same message twice ; or you risk being downvoted.