# How to have form below canvas

Tags: html, css, paperjs

I am trying to put a form below the red canvas. https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Ny6.jpg shows what happens currently.
I have tried different Divs and placing them in different code sections but nothing seems to be working. Please help me thank you.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WEBSITE.css">
    <!-- Load the Paper.js library -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/paper/dist/docs/assets/js/paper.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <script src="displayTable.js"></script>
        <canvas id="mycanvas" resize></canvas>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="backgroundTable">Color for background of table:</label>
        <form action="website.php" method="post">
            <div class="form">
                <select name="userBackgroundSelect" id="userBackgroundSelect">
                    <option value="black">Black</option>
                    <option value="red">Red</option>
                    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Scale canvas with resize attribute to full size */
canvas[resize] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, I think using a container or something would help.

Comment: Since your canvas is in position: fixed its position is ignored by other elements. just set that to something different like 'relative' or 'static' and you are good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding,you want the form to be below the canvas.According to my assesment,your canvas is postioned as fixed meaning is positioned relative to the viewport(device), which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled
Try the solution below:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
  
}

/* Scale canvas with resize attribute to full size */
canvas[resize] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: red;
  
}
```

```html
   <div>
        <script src="displayTable.js"></script>
        <canvas id="mycanvas" resize></canvas>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="backgroundTable">Color for background of table:</label>
        <form action="website.php" method="post">
            <div class="form">
                <select name="userBackgroundSelect" id="userBackgroundSelect">
                    <option value="black">Black</option>
                    <option value="red">Red</option>
                    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```